# add alertmanager to istio prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, istio, prometheus-alertmanager

How can I add alertmanager to istio prometheus deployed by official helm chart?

https://istio.io/docs/setup/install/helm/

```
helm upgrade istio install/kubernetes/helm/istio --namespace istio-system --tiller-namespace istio-system \
--set tracing.enabled=true \
--set tracing.ingress.enabled=true \
--set grafana.enabled=true \
--set kiali.enabled=true \
--set "kiali.dashboard.jaegerURL=http://jaeger-query.kaws.skynet.com/jaeger" \
--set "kiali.dashboard.grafanaURL=http://grafana.kaws.skynet.com" \
--set "kiali.prometheusAddr=http://prometheus.kaws.skynet.com"
```

Is it possible to add alertmanager to istio setup?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to add alertmanager to istio setup?

Yes, it is possible.

As i could read on [github](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/17094)

> Generally Istio is not trying to manage production grade Prometheus, grafana, etc deployments. We are doing some work to make it easy to integrate istio with your own Prometheus, kiali, etc. See https://github.com/istio/installer/tree/master/istio-telemetry/prometheus-operator as one way you can integrate with the Prometheus operator. You can define your own Prometheus setup then just add the configs to scrape istio components.

You will have to change prometheus [values and templates](https://github.com/istio/istio/tree/master/install/kubernetes/helm/istio/charts/prometheus) like [there](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus), add alertmanager yamls, and then configure it to work on istio namespace.

> How can I add alertmanager to istio prometheus deployed by official helm chart?

I would recommend to use

```
helm fetch istio.io/istio --untar
```

Which Download a chart to your local directory to view.

Then add alertmanager, and install istio helm chart from your local directory instead of helm repository.